# Inside useEffect is never run in react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have the following component. I did debugging. The function inside `useEffect` never get called.  The code reaches to `useEffect` but then does not enter inside, and therefore does not fetch records from the database. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { FetchAssignmentData } from './AssignmentDataOperations'

const AssignmentComprehensive = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.loading != true)
            props.fetchAssignment(props.match.params.id);
    }, []);

    if (props.loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    if (props.error) {
        return (<div>{props.error}...</div>)
    }

    //these are always null
    const assignmentId = props.assignmentIds[0];
    const assignment = props.assignments[assignmentId];

    return (
        //this throws error since the values are never fetched from db
        <div>{props.assignments[props.assignmentIds[0]].title}</div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    assignmentIds: state.assignmentReducer.assignmentIds,
    assignments: state.assignmentReducer.assignments,
    submissions: state.assignmentReducer.submissions,
    rubric: state.assignmentReducer.rubric,
    loading: state.assignmentReducer.loading,
    error: state.assignmentReducer.error
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return { fetchAssignment: (id) => dispatch(FetchAssignmentData(id)) };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AssignmentComprehensive);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `useEffect` second argument:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run.

So it runs only once (when the `props.loading` is`true`) and never again.

You seem to have 3 dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [props.loading, props.fetchAssignment, props.match.params.id])
```

See also: `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` [eslint rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! I see the problem for my case. The `return` statement has variables that needs to be set by `useEffect`. but `return` is rendered before `useEffect`, causing the problem. I do not know how to resolve it. Any ideas my friend?

Comment: @renakre Yes that's always the case. You should always be ready to render, You can't stop it. Therefore you should always return some JSX. You can start off with a loading state and then when the fetch is done you render the results, which I believe is what you're doing here and it's totally fine.

Comment: @Amiratak88 I am a bit confused. If I want to return something based on the database values fetched inside `useEffect`, then I will always get error since what I want to return contains undefined variables, which is the problem in my case. Do you understand what I mean? I think I am missing something here. The error I am receiving now is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: @renakre Right therefore you should render something else. (a loading state while the data is being fetched) Obviously something that's not dependent on the data. Something like `<div>Loading...</div>` and once you have the data `<div>{props.data}</div>`

Comment: the `<div>Loading...</div>` is already in the OP, I believe editing the second argument of useEffect from `[]` to my suggestion should work... maybe the 3rd one needs to be more defensive: `[props.loading, props.fetchAssignment, props.match && props.match.params && props.match.params.id]`

Comment: @Aprillion That's a good quick fix. But I think he's confused because he wants to do something else before returning JSX which is because he needs to understand the fundamentals of SPA's and async rendering.

Comment: ah, now I understand the confusion - what is happening with `useEffect` is similar to execution order of `const fn = () => console.log('second'); console.log('first'); fn();`... way more details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/748235/1176601

Comment: @renakre This is a very good [blog](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components) by Dan Abramov I think every React developer should read. If you don't have time read this [part](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/#principle-1-dont-stop-the-data-flow) which addresses this very issue.

Comment: @Aprillion when I change the `return` statement to this: `props.assignmentIds.map(assignmentId => {
           return <div>{props.assignments[assignmentId].title}</div>
      })` it worked. Do you know why?

Comment: while not having a crystal ball, `props.assignments` and `props.assignmentIds` are 2 different props... so the first one could have been `undefined` while loading and the 2nd one haven't?